# how to redirect in php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a page like www.someone.com/2011/03/05 to sample.php?dt=2011/03/05 using htaccess and php, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})/?$ sample.php?dt=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hi hsz, i used the following but it didn't redirected.  Ex:RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})$.html
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})$.html sample.php?parm=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

If you have **PHP** you don't need `.htaccess`:

Just place this on your PHP file:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.someone.com/2011/03/05");
?>
```

Comment: in my php calendar script i formed url like someone.com/2011/03/05, when user click those date links it should redirect to someone.com/sample.php?dt=2011/03/05. The purpose is i want to hide redirecting sample.php page. this is my question. can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite if you have an Apache webserver and define the rules in your .htaccess.

See for example: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php